# What is the best way to create n-size zero padding ArrayList<Int>?

Tags: kotlin

I want to create zero padding ArrayList, like this.

```
val ls = arrayListOf<Int>(0,0,0,0,0)
```

Is there a way to create n-size zero padding array list than using loop?

```
// can create zero padding array list but not looks smart
val ls = arrayListOf<Int>()
for (i in 0..n){
  ls.add(0)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `MutableList` (or a `List`) with size 5 filled with zeros:

```
val list = MutableList(5) { 0 }
```

and if you want it as an `ArrayList`:

```
val arrayList = ArrayList(list)
```

or:

```
val arrayList = ArrayList(MutableList(5) { 0 })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following

```
var arrayList = IntArray(5).toCollection(ArrayList(5))
```

or following, because as of now MutableList returns an ArrayList

```
var mutableList = MutableList(5){0} as ArrayList<Int>
```

but this may break if MutableList changes to something other than ArrayList(may be LinkedList) in future and should be avoided.

Comment: *... if MutableList changes to something other than ArrayList...* do you have any inside info about that?

Comment: No, but Documentation of MutableList function states ***Creates a new mutable list with the specified size, where each element is calculated by calling the specified
 init function.*** it does not say anything about the acutal implementation that will be returned.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a MutableList and a LinkedList?

Comment: Well when it comes to kotlin it uses java's collections but with some modifications, java for example doesn't have a notion of Mutable or Read only List, there is only List Interface and out of many other implementations of it ArrayList and LinkedList are two.

Comment: This is the implementation of MutableList: `public inline fun <T> MutableList(size: Int, init: (index: Int) -> T): MutableList<T> {
    val list = ArrayList<T>(size)
    repeat(size) { index -> list.add(init(index)) }
    return list
}` How do you expect it to change so that it returns a `LinkedList`?

Comment: The MutableList function for now returns an ArrayList but since LinkedList class can also fit the bill, some future change may return a LinkedList or any other implementation of java's List interface, so its not good to tie your code to a specific implementation.

Comment: Can you see the return type of this function ?

Comment: That means this function is only responsible for giving you a MutableList, which actual implementation it returns is not specified anywhere, and can be changed without any prior notice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205380/discussion-between-mightywoz-and-forpas).

Comment: The return type is: `MutableList<T>` (`public interface MutableCollection<E> : Collection<E>, MutableIterable<E>`), nothing to do with `LinkedList.java`.

Comment: Do you know ArrayList is a java class ?

Comment: I do know it is `java.util.ArrayList`, but this is not the point. The point is that a MutableList and a LinkedList are 2 different things by definition. Your answer contains misleading info.

Comment: Run this code snippet, and once you see the result then think and reflect.

Comment: var linkedList: MutableList<Int> = java.util.LinkedList()
    for(i in 1..10) linkedList.add(i)
    for(i in 0..9) print(linkedList[i])